# pip3 install jupyter not woking

Tags: apt, package-management, python, software-center, python3

It shows following error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1436, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 672, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 902, in move_wheel_files
    pycompile=self.pycompile,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 206, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 193, in clobber
    os.makedirs(destsubdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/os.py", line 237, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/__pycache__'

Storing debug log for failure in /home/shashank/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: Did you try `pip`?

Answer (score 0):

Installing via `pip3` needs root permissions so that it can writeto file system locations, rerun the `pip3` install with sudo:

`sudo pip3 install jupyter`

Comment: should I use pip3 or pip?

Comment: Sorry, use `pip3` I'll update my answer.

Comment: Downloading/unpacking jupyter
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement jupyter
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for jupyter
Storing debug log for failure in /home/shashank/.pip/pip.log
..........its showing this now

Comment: Can you update your question with the pip.log and some more details? This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23222104/no-distributions-at-all-found-for-some-package