# I can not connect to kernel after ı have update my spyder3

Tags: kernel, updates, spyder

I can not connect to kernel on spyder and get "an error occured while starting the kernel" just after updating my spider3. By the way, I do not use Anaconda or sth. else. My OS is ubuntu 18.04. Help me :)

An error ocurred while starting the kernel
The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist‑packages/spyder/plugins/ipythonconsole.py", line 1572, in create_kernel_manager_and_kernel_client
kernel_manager.start_kernel(stderr=stderr_handle)

File "/home/kaan/.local/lib/python3.6/site‑packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
self.write_connection_file()

File "/home/kaan/.local/lib/python3.6/site‑packages/jupyter_client/connect.py", line 472, in write_connection_file
kernel_name=self.kernel_name

File "/home/kaan/.local/lib/python3.6/site‑packages/jupyter_client/connect.py", line 137, in write_connection_file
with open(fname, 'w') as f:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/kaan/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel‑be2c68f640ce.json'
```

Comment: Another similar thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/876929/pip3-install-jupyter-not-woking

Comment: This thread does not solve my problem. Also, I think my problem is not about jupyter. I have use spyder3 for a long time and when I have updated, it gives "kernel error". By the way, I do not use jupyter and even I haven't installed it.

Comment: I have solved my problem. It's just a basic permission problem and I have solved the problem by "sudo chmod 777 /home/kaan/.local/share/jupyter/runtime" command. Thanks for support and interest. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Here, the issue was about permissions.

So, to solve it I changed the ownership of that directory using `sudo chown systemname /path`.

Note , here instead of *systemname* , it will be *kaan* and path will be 
 `/home/kaan/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/`.